# BIRT Report: Updated the query in data set. But getting column binding error based on old query

Tags: sql, report, birt

As per the requirement by client, client requested for extra fields to be added in BIRT Report. I changed the query in the data set and popultaed the data set field into the BIRT report. The issue is when i run the birt report it is showing an error message

ERROR Message:

Column binding "SUM(ITEM_QTYSOLD)" has referred to a data set column "SUM(ITEM_QTYSOLD)" which does not exist.

This SUM(ITEM_QTYSOLD) is part of the OLD sql query. I have edited the SQL query in the dataset such that SUM(ITEM_QTYSOLD) doesnt exist. what does this ERROR Message mean and what must be done to resolve it

Please note that i have updated the new sql query in data set and populated the new fields obtained from data set to birt report.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and worked for me:

1.Select your table.
2.Go to "Property Editor".
3.Go to "Binding" tab.
4.Click "Clear".
5.Select the same Data Set you are using before.
6.Try to generate the report.

Answer (score 0):

also, by clicking on the "XML Source" tab of your report, you can see details about that error when you check the scroll bar to the right. You will see a red marking where the error orrucres 
[image]
i would recommend the answer of Luke. in most cases this will help (clearing bindings and refeshing them). note: by clearing the bindings, you will loose BIRT-made data and aggregations. so be carefull